# Unix Compare Two CSV files using comm

Tags: bash, shell, csv, unix, comm

I have two CSV files. `1.csv` files has 718 entries and `2.csv` has 68000 entries.

```
#cat 1.csv
#Num    #Name  
 1      BoB
 2      Jack
 3      John
 4      Hawk
 5      Scot
 ...........

#cat 2.csv
#Num #Name
1   BoB
2   John
3   Linda
4   Hawk
5   Scot
........
```

I knew how to compare two files,when only one column(`Names`) is available in both and to get the matching `names`.

```
#comm -12 <(sort 1.csv) <(sort 2.csv)
```

Now i would like to check, If `Num` in `1.csv` is matching with `Num` in `2.csv`, What is the associated "Names" from both the `csv` files for that matched  `Num`  ?

```
Result : 

1,Bob,Bob
2,Jack,John
3,John,Linda
4,Hawk,Hawk
5,Scot,Scot
..........
```

How to do achieve this using `comm` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `join` command to perform inner join on 2 csv files on the 1st field i.e the number. Here is an example:

```
$ cat f1.csv 
1      BoB
2      Jack
3      John
4      Hawk
5      Scot
6      ExtraInF1
$ cat f2.csv 
1   BoB
3   Linda
4   Hawk
2   John
5   Scot
7   ExtraInF2
$ join <(sort -t ' ' -k 1 f1.csv) <(sort -t ' ' -k 1 f2.csv)
1 BoB BoB
2 Jack John
3 John Linda
4 Hawk Hawk
5 Scot Scot
$ join <(sort -t ' ' -k 1 f1.csv) <(sort -t ' ' -k 1 f2.csv) | tr -s ' ' ,
1,BoB,BoB
2,Jack,John
3,John,Linda
4,Hawk,Hawk
5,Scot,Scot
$
```

Note I have added few dummy rows(number 6 and 7) and also note that they haven't appeared in the output as they aren't present in both files.

`<(sort -t ' ' -k 1 f1.csv)` means process substitution i.e substitute the output of the process at this place. `sort` with delimiter as space(`-t ' '`) and on 1st key i.e 1st column(`-k 1`) and `join` by default performs inner join on 1st column of both files.

Comment: Works well for cases having the `Num` sorted, please update for unsorted cases too!

Answer (score 1):

Another one-liner for inner join using the `join` command

```
join -1 1 -2 1 <(sort 1.csv) <(sort 2.csv) |  tr -s ' ' ,

-1 2   : sort on file 1, 1st field
-2 1   : sort on file 2, 1st field
```

`tr -s` squeezes multiple spaces into a single space and replaces it by a comma(`,`)